# Scala flattening embedded list of lists

Tags: scala, list, spark-streaming

I have created a Twitter datastream that is displaying hashtag, author, and mentioned users in the below format.

`(List(timetofly, hellocake),Shera_Eyra,List(blxcknicotine, kimtheskimm))`

I can't do analysis on this format because of the embedded lists. How can I create another datastream that displays the data in this format?

`timetofly, Shera_Eyra, blxcknicotine
 timetofly, Shera_Eyra, kimtheskimm
 hellocake, Shera_Eyra, blxcknicotine
 hellocake, Shera_Eyra, kimtheskimm`

Here is my code to produce the data:

```
 val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TwitterPopularTags")
 val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(sampleInterval)) 
 val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None) 
 val data = stream.map {line => 
        (line.getHashtagEntities.map(_.getText),
        line.getUser().getScreenName(),
        line.getUserMentionEntities.map(_.getScreenName).toList)
  }
```

Comment: So you have a `Tuple3` of `List[String], String, List[String]`?  What is the desired type of your output?

Comment: I would like to see this as a list of strings

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet, `data` is a `DStream[(Array[String], String, List[String])]`. To get a `DStream[String]` in your desired format, you can use [`flatMap`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream@flatMap[U](flatMapFunc:T=>TraversableOnce[U])(implicitevidence$3:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[U]) and [`map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream@map[U](mapFunc:T=>U)(implicitevidence$2:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[U]):

```
val data = stream.map { line =>
  (line.getHashtagEntities.map(_.getText),
   line.getUser().getScreenName(),
   line.getUserMentionEntities.map(_.getScreenName).toList)
}

val data2 = data.flatMap(a => a._1.flatMap(b => a._3.map(c => (b, a._2, c))))
                .map { case (hash, user, mention) => s"$hash, $user, $mention" }
```

The `flatMap` results in a `DStream[(String, String, String)]` in which each tuple consists of a hash tag entity, user, and mention entity. The subsequent call to `map` with the pattern matching creates a `DStream[String]` in which each `String` consists of the elements in each tuple, separated by a comma and space.

Answer (score 0):

I would use for comprehension for this:

```
  val data = (List("timetofly", "hellocake"), "Shera_Eyra", List("blxcknicotine", "kimtheskimm"))

  val result = for {
    hashtag <- data._1
    user = data._2
    mentionedUser <- data._3
  } yield (hashtag, user, mentionedUser)

  result.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
(timetofly,Shera_Eyra,blxcknicotine)
(timetofly,Shera_Eyra,kimtheskimm)
(hellocake,Shera_Eyra,blxcknicotine)
(hellocake,Shera_Eyra,kimtheskimm)
```

If you would prefer a **seq of lists of strings**, rather than a **seq of tuples of strings**, then change the yield to give you a list instead: `yield List(hashtag, user, mentionedUser)`

Comment: I tried using that code but I am getting this error `value _1 is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[(Array[String], String, List[String])]`

Comment: If your data is in the form of a DStream, you could `map` over it